# jquery copy content to another text box

Tags: jquery

I have the following 2 fields in my large form...

```
 <p><input type="text" name="name" id="proname" value="" /></p>  
 <p><input type="text" name="var" id="provarname" value="" /></p>
```

I want #provarname to get the value live automatically from #proname, for example if we enter Design watch in #provarname, same time #provarname should get value design-watch(small letters and space replaced with -) , and i have written following jquery code which is not working in same manner...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#proname').live('change',function() {
        var pronameval = $(this).val();
        $('#provarname').val(pronameval.replace(' ', '-'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the event from `change` to `keydown`.

Comment: great worked, thanks, i even posting full code, so others can take help.

Comment: should we use keyup or keydown which would be best in this case?

Comment: I edited it from `keyup` to `keydown` because in theory if someone held down a key, if the event was `keyup` it would only send that key after they let go.  `keydown` should send it every time.

Answer (score 0):

As per suggestion by T.stone, the final code would be...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#proname').live('keyup',function() {
        var pronameval = $(this).val();
        $('#provarname').val(pronameval.replace(' ', '-').toLowerCase());
    });
});
```

which is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use regEx replace using `g` so it does replace all.
2. Use `keyup` instead of `change`, `change` will be triggered `onblur` of the textbox.

Change your function as below,

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KBanC/)** here

```
$('#proname').live('keyup',function() {
    var pronameval = $(this).val();
    $('#provarname').val(pronameval.replace(/ /g, '-').toLowerCase());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add  toLowerCase if you want it all in lowercase

```
var pronameval = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
```

And use keyup as been said already